ZFS unable to recv due to umount error
I am testing the ability to backup and restore a ZFS filesystem on FreeBSD 14. What I did on the original PC was:
zfs snapshot -r zroot@clone
zfs send -R zroot@clone | gzip > clone.gz
<deleted the snapshot>
<made minor edits like creating a new file>
gzcat clone.gz | zfs recv -F zroot
zfs rollback zroot@clone

That worked as expected. Now I'm trying to take that clone.gz file and use it on another system.
root@bsd:/home/free # gzcat clone.gz | zfs recv -F zroot
cannot unmount '/': unmount failed

As per the above, I am getting an umount failed error when trying to use zfs recv. I'm not really sure why it's failing and I'm not finding much information when searching. Looking at the zfs-recv manpage I tried the -u option, but it did not do anything and I still get the unmount failed error.

I'm still not sure why I cannot use zfs recv, but I found an alternative method of restoring.

Boot from the FreeBSD Live CD
Enter the Shell
Create your partition structure using gpart
Create the pool

mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /mnt
zpool create -f -o altroot=/mnt zroot nda0p4
zfs set compress=on zroot


Restore the backup using gzcat clone.gz | zfs recv -F zroot
Set the boot file system using zpool set bootfs=zroot/ROOT/default zroot

You can now exit and boot.
